# Private, everlasting version of what was previously Etherpad

Tags: collaboration

I really enjoyed Etherpad.com while it was around.  I know that the owners open-sourced the project, but I am wondering if anyone has adapted the code so that I can have private, everlasting "Etherpads" to use with some co-workers for real time collaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code is on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/).

There [are a number of clones](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20004686-248.html) out there:

1. [MeetingWords](http://meetingwords.com/)
2. [iEtherPad](http://ietherpad.com/)
3. [Sync In](http://www.cynapse.com/syncin)
4. [TitanPad](http://titanpad.com/)
5. [PiratePad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/)
6. [PrimaryPad](http://primarypad.com/)
7. [Typewith.me](http://typewith.me/)

Comment: "Sync In" appears to be what I am looking for-"there's also a pro tier, that for $2 per month (per user) gives teams a custom domain, per-note password protection, and a way to see all their notes in one place. There's also a search tool so you can find specific notes out of your entire library of work."

Answer (score 2):

Another site is http://www.stypi.com

Comment: Very clean, swift and well designed pad, thanks.